# query to concatenate columns if record duplicate

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, concat

My table has two column that is id and name. I want to do concatenate the columns if the if more than two names are same like:

```
id                                                                    name
1                                                                     John
2                                                                     David
3                                                                     Zed
4                                                                     John
5                                                                     David
6                                                                     John
7                                                                     David
8                                                                     John
9                                                                     John
```

Now I want my output that if name is repeated than the first record will remain as it is and other will be concatenated by id like

```
Id                                                                     Name
1                                                                      John
2                                                                      David
3                                                                       Zed
4                                                                      4 John
5                                                                     5 David
6                                                                     6 John 
7                                                                      7 David
8                                                                      8 John
9                                                                      9 John
```

Can anyone please help...Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `partition by` on the `name` column, and count the rows based on the order of `id`-s. Where the row number of the actual row is greater than 1, concatenate `id` and `name`, else just use the `name`.

```
with t as (
select 1 as id, 'john' as name from dual union all
select 2, 'david' from dual union all
select 3, 'zed' from dual union all
select 4, 'john' from dual union all
select 5, 'david' from dual union all
select 6, 'john' from dual union all
select 7, 'david' from dual union all
select 8, 'john' from dual union all
select 9, 'john' from dual
)
select 
  id, 
  case 
    when row_number() over (partition by name order by id) > 1 then id || ' ' || name
    else name
  end as name
from t order by id;

        ID NAME
---------- ----------------------------------------------
         1 john
         2 david
         3 zed
         4 4 john
         5 5 david
         6 6 john
         7 7 david
         8 8 john
         9 9 john

9 rows selected.
```

To treat `john`, `JOHN`, `joHN`, etc. equally, simply change the `partition by` column, e.g `upper(name)`.

```
select 
  id, 
  case 
    when row_number() over (partition by upper(name) order by id) > 1 then id || ' ' || name
    else name
  end as name
from t order by id;
```

Answer (score 1):

I found by only using update you can also do this:

```
UPDATE concatenate c2
SET c2.payer_name = source_id ||' '|| payer_name
WHERE c2.rowid > 
(
    SELECT min(c1.rowid)
    FROM concatenate c1  
    WHERE upper(c1.payer_name)=upper(c2.payer_name)
);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [A] order by [A])Col 
FROM [dbo].[STG_Info] )

SELECT [VERSION], [A],[B] ,CASE WHEN Col>1 
THEN CONCAT(CTE.[A],'',cast(CTE.Col as varchar))
ELSE
[A]
END AS NewColumn
FROM CTE
```

Comment: please always add an explanation to your code4